# Can someone explain the derivation for this profit function

Tags: derivatives, economics

So, how come the derivative ends up as f'-q/l

Some other identities are qi/q=Li/L, qi=Li/L * f(L) and L=sumLi

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nw8ZT.jpg)

Comment: Try typing out your question and adding your thoughts so people can understand better what it is that you're asking, and answer appropriately.

Comment: You have left off all the context, and all the definitions.  We don't have your text book in front of us, and it is hard to guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At its current state, I'm not sure if it's possible to answer the question, but I can start computing the derivative of the following expression:
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{d}{dL_i} \left( \frac{p L_i f(L)}{L} \right) &=
p\frac{d}{dL_i} \left( \frac{ L_i f(L)}{L} \right) \\
&= p \frac{L \left[ L_i f\right]' - L_if\left[L \right]'}{L^2} \\
&= p \frac{L L_i' f + L L_i f' - L_i f L'}{L^2} \\
&= p \frac{L L_i' + L_i \left(Lf'  - f' L\right)}{L^2} \\
&= p \left[ \frac{L_i' f}{L} + \frac{L_i}{L}\left(f' - \frac{fL'}{L} \right) \right]
\end{split} 
$$
... which is already quite close to the desired answer. The main point in the differentiation was to remember the rule of differentiating
$$
\left[\frac{f}{g} \right]' = \frac{gf' - fg'}{g^2}
$$
The "dot/prime" of course represents differentiation with respect to $L_i$ in these equations. Can you work out the solution with this?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much!

Comment: Don´t forget to mark the answer as accepted. Thanks.

Comment: @mrsdosado You're welcome. If you find the answer useful, you can mark it as accepted. Thank you.

Comment: I did! Sorry, didn't figure out I needed to do it at first.